# Create a REST API wrapper for Node.js TCP server

Tags: node.js, rest, http, tcp

I have managed to create a TCP server using node.js which looks something like this.

```
const net = require('net');
const port = 7070;
const host = '127.0.0.1';

const server = net.createServer();
  server.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log('TCP Server is running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

I am wanting to create a http rest API wrapper around this. So that I can send messages from my TCP server to my TCP client. For example if I create a URL http://example.com/api/send-message and when I hit this URL it will trigger my TCP server to send a message.

I'm just so confused as to how I can even go about doing this as the TCP server and REST API server are on different ports. Please can anyone help

Comment: Why not to use Express or similar? Just wondering

Comment: Yeah I can use express but I'm not sure how it will work as they're both on seperate ports

Comment: You can configure express to run an HTTP server in any port you wish. `express().listen( port, () => { // callback }); `

Comment: Yeah but I thought they wouldn't be able to share the same port as one would be a TCP server and the other http server or am I mistaken?

Comment: HTTP runs with the TCP protocol so basically any http server is also a TCP server. Anyways you cannot have two http or tcp server in the same port, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by creating a node.js app that acts as a tcp client that talks to my node.js tcp server. In the client I integrated express. Express creates the API and then on each endpoint I created a TCP connection that communicates with my TCP server and then the response is sent back to my http API

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000;
const net = require('net');
const client = new net.Socket();


var tcpPort = 7070;
var tcpIP = '127.0.0.1';

app.get('/',function(req, res){

 client.connect(tcpPort, tcpIP);
 client.write('Hello world');
 client.on('data', function(data) {
    client.destroy();
    res.send({hello:data.toString()});
 });

});
```